# Retrieve one parameter value from uri with two '&' in c#

Tags: c#, string, uri

I have url like https://test.com?id=346?para1=abc&para2=pqr and this can also be https://test.com?para1=abc&para2=par

I need to get para1 value i.e 'abc' alone from url
Http parse function only works with url with one '?' not with two

Comment: Your first `?` is the query start. The other one is a just a string value. Still the first example is not a valid format. What generated this format ? The only thing i can think of is some CMS

Comment: Yeah from powerapps it's generated and inworkflow we process like this